# Can I change an app's price after uploading it on the iTunes app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to upload an app to the iTunes app store, and change the price of that app in six months. Can I do this?

Comment: Yes you can change the price and no apple does not review it again. Just go to the Dev portal and change the price and you should be just fine.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your useful information

Comment: Please let me know how much time it'll take for reflect new price to app?

Comment: It is hard to say, but it should be only a few hours.

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can do that, not a problem. Just log into itunes connect, manage apps, select your app, and go to 'rights and pricing'.

Comment: After change it, Dose apple will review it again? OR it'll changed at a time?

Comment: You don't need to submit a new binary to change the price, so no app review is necessary. Just need to provide a price change effective date (could be date range also).

Comment: How long will it take to update in iTunes Store?

Comment: My app price change updated within about an hour.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it. Just go to [iTuneConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) and select the app and go to "Rights and Pricing" to change the price and effective date.